# No ADT plugin options available

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 and installed Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo) for Java Developers along with the Android SDK.  When I add the following URL into the `work With` field under Eclipse's <kbd>Install New Software</kbd> menu:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse

No plugins appear between the "Work With" and <kbd>Options</kbd> sections. I understand I'm supposed to be able to select <kbd>Developer Tools</kbd>. I get nothing. I've tried linking to http vice https. Also, downloading the zip from the android dev site itself yields the same result.  When I run <kbd>Check for Updates</kbd>, it comes back saying nothing to update. I also ran "Test Connection" for the above URL and it comes back positive.

Any advice?

Comment: Could you make a screenshot of your problem? Have you tried to "Add…" the site to your list, with a name?

Comment: also add your eclipse error log

Comment: The Install New Software page is at... Is there something special I'm supposed to do after selecting the Android URL other than hit enter? You can see there's nothing between "Work with" and "Details" The Error Log doesn't supply much interesting info. Just complains about a help document error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is an Eclipse visualization bug: try to resize the dialog window as it appears minimized

Comment: cerealk is exactly right. I increased the resolution, rebooted, and resized the dialog window to something bigger and "Developer Tools" is now visible. It is an Eclipse UI bug but trying to do this on a netbook probably didn't help matters. Please note I had to reboot my system to get this to work but thinking back on it I probably could have fixed it by restarting Eclipse. Thanks very much everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Click the "Add..." button to the top right.  Then enter the name (I just put "Android") and location (https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse).  At the right side of the work with field there is an arrow that brings up the list of sites.  Clicking Android adds the Developer Tools item to the list below.  From there you can expand it and check whatever you need.

Comment: Understand that's the way it's supposed to be done but Developer Tools never appears below the Work With box.  I'm beginning to think it's a problem with my Display settings - I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop mode on my netbook which probably leads to weird behavior with GNOME.

Comment: What shows below in the name/version area?  Does it stay at "There is no site selected" or "Pending..." or something else?